# How to Show important places route between two locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an app that displays some important points in a map between two locations specific **single route**. like as following example.if any one know about these related works please let me know.

example  **point A**-> x     **point B**-> Y

in given  X & Y single route show   Hotels / filling stations etc....  using check boxes

**Is this possible**? If yes, can you point some **tutorials**?