# Google maps crash on android - setup

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to add the map feature to my application. I followed the steps on google and added all the good staff in my manifest. here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.events.activities"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.events.activities.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.events.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.events.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.events.activities.MasterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_master" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now I Have an Activity with tabs ,each tab is a fragment, I want that one of the fragments will show a map (starched all over it) so I have created this `map_frag.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the fragment class:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_frag, container, false);

         return rootView;
     }
}
```

But there is a crash each time I opening the tab, here is the LogCat:

```
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at com.events.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:23)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     ... 19 more
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.events.activities-2.apk
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
11-12 06:41:05.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     ... 22 more
```

I don't understand why I get an error on `Binary XML file`.

**There is one more thing:**
 I cant import this `GoogleMap` class to my `MapFragment` as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978190/add-google-maps-api-v2-in-a-fragment) SO question.
Maybe there is something I need to add to  my project

Comment: change your min sdk to 12

Comment: @ Raghunandan I am getting the same error

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your project?

Comment: @ Raghunandan, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. then reference the same in your project

Comment: I have added google play services lib to my project, and still the same...

Answer (score 0):

sorry dude you can not use  fragment in MapFragment layout file because android does not support nested fragment through xml. you need to add fragment runtime.

1) Remove fragment from xml layout file.

2) Put there blank LinerarLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lnrMap" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

3) In your MapFragment.java

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.lnrMap, mapFragment);
        ft.commit();

Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        googleMap = mapFragment.getExtendedMap();

                        if (googleMap != null) {
                        // Write your code for map operation here
                            t.cancel();
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 500);
```

Comment: I am getting an error (compilation) on this `ft.replace(R.id.lnrMap, mapFragment);`

Comment: then you can use getFragmentManager() instead

Comment: need to go for lunch will come an figure out after lunch. min while try to resolve compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was missing in my manifest:

```
<meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vlad Ioffe said, try to add the below code into the manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

It works for me perfectly!!!!