# MapFragment in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement GoogleMap api while using fragments - used for slidebar menu.
Here is fragment code

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
private GoogleMap map;
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
public MapFragment(){}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

        //...

    //...

    return rootView;
}
```

Layout xml

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I've already tried [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978190/add-google-maps-api-v2-in-a-fragment), but this line in eclipse is an error

```
  map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

> Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: try this `map = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: Already tried that, but thanks, problem was in automatic imports in eclipse. I edited my post.

Comment: Or did't. That did't work as it replaces extended Fragment.

Comment: what is your minimum sdk version?

Comment: I set minimum of 11 in AndroidManifest

Comment: have you imported SupportMapFragment as a android.support.v4.app.SupportMapFragment?

Comment: I now have problem with "attempting to create multiple DataRequestDispatchers" error. I tried everything.

Comment: Ok I solved it by changing everywhere from com.android.app.Fragment to com.android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: To solve this problem, you can follow my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863507/how-to-implement-google-maps-within-a-fragment-and-use-the-googlemap-object/26863913#26863913