# Getting NullPointerException on setting google MAP in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i'm trying to set Google Map on android so i have set all things on, but when i try to get the fragment that contain the map the error log display a `NullPointerException` error. the error is due to it's not recognize the map

**My XML Layout :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.unchainedappli.SpotFragement">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

The `onCreate` method

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));

}
```

**The error log :**

```
0-17 08:12:32.884    2373-2373/com.example.user.unchainedappli E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.unchainedappli, PID: 2373
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.unchainedappli.SpotFragement.onCreate(SpotFragement.java:69)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1481)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have not mentioned API key for Google maps V2 xml layout

Comment: but no it must be in AndroidManifiest.

Comment: i said about the AndroidMainfest.xml file . Are you sure you have put you API key

Comment: Yes. i'm the null pointer exception is not about this, but because an element is null and it's my google map this line `GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, The error clearly states that exception in SpotFragement.java file.line no 69. Go through that line.. sometimes you are passing null values to a method/function or retrieving an null values etc..

Comment: this is the line
 `GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: Have you added the required permissions and Google Map API key in your manifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, i've said that i've set all things perfectly

Comment: setcontentview(R.layout.YOURLAYOUTNAME);

Comment: is a Fragment and not an activity. The fragment have the onCreateView method

Comment: @KANDROIDOS the hulk is right. The error happens in the onCreate method of your activity because the activity has no layout set. So the fragment may be specified in your layout xml but your activity does not know about that. Thus findFragmentById() does not find it. Thus the NPE.

Comment: I’m talking about a fragment and not an activity. i put the google map in a fragment and not an activity.

Comment: @KANDROIDOS fragement is in one particular layout right. So add setcontentview() in your oncreate() method and try it.

Comment: to explain for the last time. i set the google map in a framgent and not an activity. So is a fragment that implement the google map fragment. The fragments have the onCreateView instead ofsetcontentview()

Comment: Ok.. Try this one..mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

Comment: @KANDROIDOS this question in Stackoverflow might help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978190/add-google-maps-api-v2-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
FragmentManager frag = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

final SupportMapFragment myfrag = (SupportMapFragment) frag 
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: Have you extend your class by Fragment?

Comment: Yes, normaly is a fragment

Comment: use this 'mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();'

Comment: sorry neither this also