# Google map fragment to be called in multiple activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-play-services

I'm new Android Developing and I want to know how can I create a fragment of map in and call it in multiple activity layouts?

Please help with proper description as I am new to Android Development.
I already have the API key required from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think this question is a possible duplicate. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978190/add-google-maps-api-v2-in-a-fragment).

Secondly, there are a number of tutorials online regarding this; including one given by Google. Please refer to these links:

1. [Google Maps Android API v2 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)
2. [Vogella Google Maps Android API v2 - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)