# Android map in fragment nullpointer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my project im trying to implement[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978233/1667868) for managing a map in a dynamic added fragment.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(KIEL, 15));
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorBackground"
    tools:context="com.example.sven.questy.GameFragments.MapFragment">

    <fragment

         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

WHen i run the app i get a nullpointer exception on:

```
 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

The id of the map = map ( android:id="@+id/map").

Why the nullpointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using nested fragments, you should use getChildFragmentManager()

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

And I recommend you to use getMapAsync method, because getMap is deprecated

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        setupMap(googleMap);
    }
});
```

Comment: After using getChildFragmentManager() I don't get any inflating error. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [`findViewById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) on the view you get, not using the fragment manager. The map is attached to the view

```
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    map = v.findViewById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```